# python file error while execution

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am creating a simple python file in unix, just to open and write some test in it, but getting error while execution. Using Python 2.4.3

```
file = open(“testfile.txt”, “w”)

file.write(“This is a test”) 

file.write(“To add more lines.”)

file.close()
```

Error:

```
./test.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.py: line 1: `file = open(“testfile.txt”, “w”)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `“` is not a valid quote in Python. Try copying and pasting this code into your file/terminal and you should then realise the difference.

```
file = open("testfile.txt", "w")
file.write("This is a test")
file.write("To add more lines.")
file.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are using curly quotes `“”` (e.g. from Microsoft Word, etc..) rather than actual single and double quote chars `'' ""`.

Make sure you are using a regular text editor, not a rich text editor.  That's the problem.

Comment: ./test.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.py: line 1: `file = open("testfile.txt","w") '

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the "smart" quotes that need to be plain ASCII `"` characters you need a "shebang" line as the first line of the script. Otherwise it is likely to be treated as a shell script and handed to */bin/sh* for execution. You should insert this as the first line of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Or run it via `python ./x.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I think quotes are the problem.
can you try a content manager

```
 with open('testfile.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write("Your Text Here")
```

use of context managers is to properly manage resources. In fact, that's the reason we use a context manager . The act of opening a file consumes a resource (called a file descriptor), and this resource is limited by your OS. Similarly writing.
 That is to say, there are a maximum number of files a process can have open at one time.

Comment: ./test1.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test1.py: line 1: `with open("testfile.txt", 'w') as output_file:'